# Impossible to start Ubuntu after installing lxde

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, lightdm, lxde

i just tried installing lxde on my Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to try working with two different screen at the same time. So to do that typed CTRL+ALT+F2 to go in another terminal and then i typed the command: startx exec startlxde -- :1 vt8. Actually it didn't work, it appeared just a black screen on display 1 (i've seen it typing CTRL+ALT+F8). By the way the problem is another one. Now when i reboot the system it appears the ligthdm screen (before this it didn't used to appear) which asks me the password. If i put the password it tries to start but immedialtely comes back to the lightdm. I can just start the system as guest user. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

alt+ctrl+f1 'tty'
remove xde

```
$ sudo apt-get purge xde
```

remove ubuntu desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop
```

re install the ubuntu desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: mmm ... it doesn't work ... i still can't login